# post event to facebook with place page id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

via the graph api, I create events for facebook pages I have the create_event and manage_pages privileges for.

I post to https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/events with the usual name, location, start_time, street, city parameters. Works perfectly.

However, I haven't found a way to submit a certain place_id for the event (e.g. FB-ID of the venue). This is possible using the web client. When creating an event, you can select a place/venue, the resulting event page shows that place on the map and links to the place page. Events created via the api only show the location name as text.

I tried place_page_id and several others as parameters, but nothing worked.

Has anybody done that successfully?

Thanks

Comment: Tangential question here.  Is there a way to post an existing event to a facebook page that you manage via the API?  I haven't been able to find one.  Seems odd since you can add a new event to a page via API, and you can add an existing event to a page via the interface, but you can't add an existing event to a page via the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No with the current API it is not possible.  Here's the only parameters for creating an event available.  They are the same for **user** events as well as **page** events.

name (string)
start_time (timestamp)
end_time (timestamp)
description (string)
location (string)
privacy_type (string)

Comment: And so there is, maybe you should log a documentation defect with Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ to report that those fields exists on the root of event to be POSTed to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  A [poorly documented property](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/142316839215598) of Event is location_id.  Works fine.

The way I handle it is to search for type=place and if I find the place in the vast Facebook data store I use the id of that place in the location_id field.  If I don't find the right place I use the information I have for street and city.  (If you have location_id you really don't need street and city).